# Kafka could not create internal topics after 32 topics created

Tags: apache-kafka

We have `9` microservices that creates `32` topics (`2` of them from beginning , `30` of them from internal) , after I make a new join kafka gets down. Is there any limitation that only `32` topics can be created with Kafka, or how can I solve this?

Thank you for your time.

```
Started SpringBootCounterMS in 4.652 seconds (JVM running for 7.59)
2018-07-04 10:39:29.513  INFO 14956 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [counter-service-3ca6bb7e-addd-445e-a22b-8b7be1b3b6c7-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2018-07-04 10:39:29.514  INFO 14956 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams    : stream-client [counter-service-3ca6bb7e-addd-445e-a22b-8b7be1b3b6c7]State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
2018-07-04 10:39:30.579  INFO 14956 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=counter-service-3ca6bb7e-addd-445e-a22b-8b7be1b3b6c7-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=counter-service] Marking the coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) dead
2018-07-04 10:39:30.599  WARN 14956 --- [-StreamThread-2] o.a.k.s.p.i.InternalTopicManager         : stream-thread [main] Could not create internal topics: Empty response for client request. Retry #0
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating JVM to a 64bit one solves this problem. It is a outofmemory error.